# Using existing Ansible roles to create a custom Docker image

Tags: linux, docker, ansible, devops

I currently use Ansible to manage and deploy a fleet of servers.

I wish to start using Docker for some applications and would like to build a Docker image using the same scripts we use to configure on non Dockerized hosts.

For example we have an Ansible role that builds Nginx with 3rd party modules, would like to use the same role to build a Docker image with the custom Nginx.

Any ideas how I would get this done?

Answer (score 1):

There is the "Ansible Container" project, https://www.ansible.com/integrations/containers/ansible-container. That page points also to the github repo.

It is not clear how well maintained it is, but their reasoning and approach makes sense.

Consider that you might have some adjustments to do regarding two aspects:

- a container should do only one thing (microservice)
- how to pass configuration to the container at runtime (Docker has some guidelines, such as environmental variables if possible or mounting a volume with the configuration files)

Comment: Thanks I will look into it (and accept the answer if it makes sense).    About the container doing one thing is that a hard rule?  Because some projects will use that philosophy, but other might just use Docker with as a monolith image that has all the services (for dev environment only).  That way all our projects can use Docker images for dev machines even though it wont run in production as a container.

Comment: Having the container doing only one thing is not an hard rule in the sense that technically there is no enforcement. On the other hand, it is a best practice and in my experience you will regret not following it. I suggest you investigate https://docs.docker.com/compose/ to obtain the "monolith" in a Docker idiomatic way.

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfect example where the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script should be used.

It has been developed to allow ansible scripts to target both virtual machines and docker containers. It had been developed when distros did switch to systemd which was hard to enable for containers. When overwriting /usr/bin/systemctl then the docker container will then look good enough for ansible that all the old scripts will continue to run, installing rpm/deb, and having 'service:'s started and enabled.